# R Extract names from text

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to extract a list of rugby players names from a string. The string contains all of the information from a table, containing the headers (team names) as well as the name of the player in each position for each team. It also has the player ranking but I don't care about that.

Important - a lot of player rankings are missing. I found a solution to this however doesn't handle missing rankings (for example below Rabah Slimani is the first player not to have a ranking recorded).

Note, the 1-15 numbers indicate positions, and there's always two names following each position (home player and away player).

Here's the sample string:

`" Team Sheets     #            FRA France      RPI             IRE Ireland      RPI     1        Jefferson Poirot     72           Cian Healy     82     2        Guilhem Guirado     78           Rory Best     85     3        Rabah Slimani               Tadhg Furlong     85     4        Arthur Iturria     82           Iain Henderson     84     5        Sebastien Vahaamahina     84           James Ryan     92     6        Wenceslas Lauret     82           Peter O'Mahony     93     7        Yacouba Camara     70           Josh van der Flier     64     8        Kevin Gourdon               CJ Stander     91     9        Maxime Machenaud               Conor Murray     87     10        Matthieu Jalibert               Johnny Sexton     90     11        Virimi Vakatawa               Jacob Stockdale     89     12        Henry Chavancy               Bundee Aki     83     13        Rémi Lamerat               Robbie Henshaw     78     14        Teddy Thomas               Keith Earls     89     15        Geoffrey Palis               Rob Kearney     80      Substitutes      #            FRA France      RPI             IRE Ireland      RPI     16        Adrien Pelissie               Sean Cronin     84     17        Dany Priso     70           Jack McGrath     70     18        Cedate Gomes Sa     71           John Ryan     86     19        Paul Gabrillagues     77           Devin Toner     90     20        Marco Tauleigne               Dan Leavy     80     21        Antoine Dupont     92           Luke McGrath         22        Anthony Belleau     65           Joey Carbery     86     23        Benjamin Fall               Fergus McFadden         "`

Note - it comes from here: https://www.rugbypass.com/live/six-nations/france-vs-ireland-at-stade-de-france-on-03022018/2018/info/

So basically what I want is just the list of names with the team names as the headers e.g.

```
France             Ireland

Jefferson Poirot   Cian Healy
Guilhem Guirado    Rory Best
...              ...
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: DO you think my answer solves your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this on an advanced notepad editor and tried to find occurrences of 2 consecutive numbers and replaced those with a new line. the ReGex is

```
\d+\s+\d+
```

Once you are done replacing, you will be left with 2 names in each line separated by a number. Then use the below ReGex to replace that number with a single tab

```
\s+\d+\s+
```

Hope that helps